# Getting TortoiseSVN to set a file's modified time to the timestamp of the latest revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I seem to remember being able to get [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) to set the last-modified timestamp for files to the timestamp from the revision when performing an update. So if someone committed a file five days ago and I update it, the modified timestamp will be five days ago, not today.

Where is the option?

Comment: I assume you have a good reason for wanting to do this and you know what you're doing, but for posterity, I thought I'd add a warning... if you use this option along with some kind of incremental build tool (such as make), files may change due to the update but still have a timestamp from before your last build, which will mean they won't be re-built the next time you build.  This can be a source of all sorts of strange errors (mostly relating to linking, in languages that have linking).

Comment: My related question is: can this be done on a per-repository basis, rather than for all repositories?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When I go to the Settings option in the TortoiseSVN menu, I see an option to "Set file dates to the last commit time." This may be what you're looking for.

#### Invoke the Settings option

[image: Screenshot of how to invoke the TortoiseSVN settings dialog]

#### Set the option

[image: Screenshot of the option to get SVN to timestamp the checked out files with the original file modification date, not the current time]

Comment: I knew it was a problem between chair and keyboard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I am not sure if Tortoise uses the SVN client as a backend, but if it does, there is an option in the Subversion configuration file:

```
use-commit-times = yes
```

Sorry if this doesn't apply on your platform, but I'll mention it anyway. It works for those using the SVN command-line client.

Comment: At least there's a button for launching and editor for the svn config file in Tortoise's preferences UI.

Comment: Thanks!  On my client-provided windows platform I use both cygwin and Tortoise: I can separately set ~/.subversion/config to `use-commit-times = yes` and I confirmed that worked in my cygwin.  I can turn it back off in cygwin and then turn it on in Tortoise.  At least for cygwin, we get separate config - not sure if non-cygwin behaves differently.