# How can I keep original file timestamp when checking into subversion?

Tags: svn

Very similar to [How can I keep the original file [commit] timestamp on Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171939/how-can-i-keep-original-file-timestamp-on-subversion), but I'm interested in preserving the timestamp on the commit side rather than propagating it on the checkout / update side.

Specifically, I'm checking some (very old) unversioned files into my shiny new SVN setup, so I'll have everything in one place, but I want their timestamps to reflect the actual modified times rather than the time I loaded them into the system (which will be virtually the same for all of them).

Are there any solutions for this?  I've searched and searched the SVN documentation available online but haven't found anything that seems to do what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly it appears that Subversion doesn't do that.  Here's a long-running request for what appears to be what you want:
[Subversion issue](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1256)

Comment: Ah, thank you for the link to the issue number - it confirms what I suspected.  However, it seems as though there isn't a workaround or alternative solution suggested there.  Do you (or does anyone else) have one?

Comment: I don't know, I have never had a need for this.  Perhaps a custom property?  I just did that with 'svn propset originalmodifiedtime "2001-12-31 21:40:34" DoxygenMainpage.cs' and then retrieved it with 'svn propget originalmodifiedtime DoxygenMainpage.cs' and it returned the correct value.  Depending upon exact need this might serve.  Do note that originalmodifiedtime is a new, custom property and could be named anything you wish.  You might read about custom properties and consider nameing it company initials:originalmodifiedtime to avoid name collisions.  Like 'att:originalmodifiedtime'