# SVN checkout files that have been committed within given time period

Tags: bash, svn, datetime, timestamp

I'm writing a deployment bash script that will publish recent changes in source control to a different machine. I'm new to svn from the command line (have used it in development for years) and new to bash scripting.

I need a way to checkout only files that have been modified recently. Something like this:

`svn checkout svn://server/repo/project/trunk -mtime -1d4h`

The idea being this would only checkout files that have been committed within the last 28 hours.

Comment: AFAIK there is no feature like that into SVN. You probably will need to write a script for that where will checkout with depth=empty, list the log , found the last commit into the last 28 hours and rollback wrapping the filenames updating each one...  not so hard, but need some work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't checkout *changes*, you get only *some state* of some part of repository (i.e "revision"), which will include all files, existing in this node (subdirectory) in this revision (and added|modified in **any** revision before *this revision*, including *this revision*)
2. [Date format specification in Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates) doesn't allow "relative date-time", only absolute values
3. Scripts, which export|save outside repository all files, changed in revision|revision range, exist and can be found in Net ([Subversion Command Line Script to export changed files](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/subversion-export-changed-files-cli-v2/) as good bash-sample)

Consequences of the above notes

- You must to supply correct Subversion-style date or revision number for starting point
- Relative date with free-form specification can be easy constructed with bash [date command](http://www.manpager.com/linux/man1/date.1.html) (`-d "28 hours before"`) and [stored in variable](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/), which can be used as parameter for electrictoolbox's script
- Deploy of files from export-directory to final destination is final part (heavy environment-specific, no suggestions here now)

Answer (score 0):

I found something simpler to suite my needs based on this:
[How can I keep the original file [commit] timestamp on Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171939/how-can-i-keep-the-original-file-timestamp-on-subversion)

I checkout or update a working copy of the project using `--config-option config:miscellany:use-commit-times=yes` which sets the timestamps on the filesystem equal to the last checkout time. I then use a standard `find` command. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

function listfn {

   while read file; do

      if [[ !( $file =~ ^.*\.svn.*$ ) ]]; then
          echo $file
      fi

   done

}


svn checkout --config-option config:miscellany:use-commit-times=yes svn://server/repo/project/trunk project-fordeploy

find project-fordeploy -mtime -1d4h | listfn
```