# Configuring .subversion/config on a jenkins slave

Tags: jenkins, svn

I'm trying to keep keep original file time stamp as mentioned in this Stack Overflow question:
[How can I keep the original file [commit] timestamp on Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171939/how-can-i-keep-the-original-file-commit-timestamp-on-subversion)

I edited the .subversion/config on Jenkins masters, but I'm not sure how I can tell my Jenkin slaves how to keep the original timestamp when they pull code.

Answer (score 0):

This was a misunderstanding on my part. The Subversion plugin adds Subversion support by SVNKit and from the SVNKit website:

"By default SVNKit tries to obtain all necessary information from the [tunnels] section of the config file that is located in the default SVN run-time configuration area. However if that information is not complete or not found at all, SVNKit tries then to use predefined system properties listed beneath."

So I'm assuming would use the config file on Jenkins Master